# How to get sockfd from kernel space?

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-kernel

Is there a way to get the `sockfd` from a `struct sock` or any other way that would allow me to uniquely identify the socket / connection I'm working with in kernel space?

I need this piece of information in the context of a device driver for a network adapter.

Comment: And how would that uniquely identify a socket/connection?  Which type of connection is it? e.g: TCP connections are uniquely identified by (interface, source address, source port, dest address, dest port) tuples.

Comment: I'm actually in a situation where I'm not establishing the connection myself but asking the NIC to do it. The NIC is returning an acknowledgment for my connection opening request but the local port will be a NIC-handled port, not a host-stack-handled port. I need to get the file handle linked to my `sock` structure to demultiplex incoming packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it was impossible but actually there is a way, at least for simple cases where we have no duplicate file descriptors for a single socket. I'm answering my own question, hoping it'll help people out there.

```
int get_sockfd(struct sock *sk)
{
    int sockfd;
    unsigned int i;
    struct files_struct *current_files;
    struct fdtable *files;
    struct socket *sock;
    struct file *sock_filp;

    sockfd = -1;

    sock = sk->sk_socket;
    sock_filp = sock->file;

    current_files = current->files;
    files = files_fdtable(current_files);

    for (i = 0; files->fd[i] != NULL; i++) {
            if (sock_filp == files->fd[i]) {
                    sockfd = i;
                    break;
            }
    }

    return sockfd;
}
```

You would of course want to check for NULL pointers, starting with `struct sock *sk` passed in param.

So, basically, the idea is that the numerical value of a file descriptor (a sockfd is just a regular file descriptor, after all) corresponds to the index of its corresponding entry in a process open files table. All we have to do when given a `struct sock *sk` pointer is loop over the open files table of the current process until the addres pointed to by `sk->sk_socket->file` matches an entry in the table.